# OS X version checking in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am developing a Cocoa application and need to check whether the current OS X version is OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard

If the current version is Snow Leopard, I need to close the application with an error alert.

How can I find the current OS X version?

Comment: Why won't (can't) the application run on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 9):

The relevant Apple documentation can be found in *Using SDK-Based Development*: [Determining the Version of a Framework](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW1).

They suggest either testing the existence of a specific class or method or to check the framework version number, e.g. `NSAppKitVersionNumber` or `NSFoundationVersionNumber`. The relevant frameworks also declare a number of constants for different os versions ([NSApplication constants](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSAppKitVersionNumber), [Foundation Constants](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSFoundationVersionNumber)).

The relevant code can be as simple as:

```
if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) > NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5) {
    // Code for 10.6+ goes here
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple ways you could do this.

1. You could check for the existence of a 10.6 only class:

   ```
   Class snowLeopardOnlyClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSRunningApplication");
   if (snowLeopardOnlyClass != nil) {
     NSLog(@"I'm running on Snow Leopard!");
   }
   ```
2. Use a system function (like [`Gestalt`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Gestalt_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000036-CH1g-F01632)) to determine the OS version:

   ```
   #import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
   SInt32 major = 0;
   SInt32 minor = 0;   
   Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMajor, &major);
   Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMinor, &minor);
   if ((major == 10 && minor >= 6) || major >= 11) {
     NSLog(@"I'm running on Snow Leopard (at least!)");
   }
   ```

Comment: Your second test will fail on OSX 11.0 (assuming there is an 11.0 someday) even though it's a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

On UNIX systems you can use the `uname(3)` system call. See

```
$ man 3 uname
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main()
{
    struct utsname un;

    uname(&un);
    printf("sysname: %s\nnodename: %s\nrelease: %s\nversion: %s\nmachine: %s\n",
        un.sysname, un.nodename, un.release, un.version, un.machine);
}
```

On Mac OS X 10.8.5 I get "9.8.0" as the release number. See [list of releases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29#Releases). 10.0 is Mac OS X 10.6, 10.2.0 is Mac OS X 10.6.2.

Comment: This is definitely not the correct way to check the system version on Mac OS X. `Gestalt` as outlined by Dave Long is the correct way. `uname` is not guaranteed to return anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this source: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000067.php - there is described 4 ways how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself ,Imimplemented the alert in main.m as follows :

```
#ifndef NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5
#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5 949
#endif 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SInt32 major = 0;
    SInt32 minor = 0;   
    Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMajor, &major);
    Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMinor, &minor);
    if ((major == 10 && minor >= 6) || major >= 11) {

        CFUserNotificationDisplayNotice(0, kCFUserNotificationCautionAlertLevel,NULL, NULL, NULL, CFSTR("Maestro"), CFSTR("This version is not compatible."),  CFSTR("Ok"));
        return 0;
    }
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}
```