# version checking before application launch cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I am developing an application in cocoa which is not compatible with snow os .Is it possible to show an alert message while user try to launch the application in snow os?

Comment: Er, do you really mean it's compatible with 10.5 and not 10.6?  The more normal question would be how to specify that it's compatible with 10.6 and not 10.5.

Comment: yes my app is not compatible with 10.6 and now i need to show an alert message in version 10.6.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115373/os-version-checking-in-cocoa

Comment: Probably the best solution is to make the app compatible with 10.6.

Answer (score 3):

```
#ifndef NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5
#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5 949
#endif 
if(NSAppKitVersionNumber>NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5)
{
    NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Failed OS check"
    defaultButton:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"")
    alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil 
    informativeTextWithFormat:
    @"I am a hard up developer that cannot afford to keep up with my 
    customers. If only they would buy more of my apps i could afford 
    maybe a new mac mini with Snow Leopard on it and bring my 
    App upto date. The problem is that unless i can bring my 
    app upto date i am not likely to get many customers at all.
    If you know how that film with Art Garfunkel ended could
    you please let me know."];
    [alert runModal];
} else {
// start up app
}
```

*(thanks adium)

Comment: Ahh, i see you already asked this and it was already answered for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the key `LSMinimumSystemVersion` to your app's Info.plist. As per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-113253):

> This string must be of the form n.n.n
>   where n is a number. The first number
>   is the major version number of the
>   system. The second and third numbers
>   are minor revision numbers. For
>   example, to support Mac OS X v10.4 and
>   later, you would set the value of this
>   key to "10.4.0".

Comment: I made the same mistake on the questioner's previous question. The app works fine on Leopard, but for some unspecified reason, will/should not work on Snow Leopard.