# How to determine MAC OS X version (10.5,10.6,10.7) from Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find Mac OS X version number in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492038/find-mac-os-x-version-number-in-objective-c)

My application needs to be run on (10.5,10.6,10.7) . I have some different implementation pieces for each of them. So I want to be able to check OSX version from my APP.

How can I do it?

What is the best way to do that? Is there any function like if([osx version])...?

P.S. I'm aware of this question [How can I determine the running Mac OS X version programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157759/how-can-i-determine-the-running-mac-os-x-version-programmatically)  I just couldn't find what I want for all that 3 versions.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This might be a useful [Link](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000067.php) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115373/os-version-checking-in-cocoa)

Comment: I was aware only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157759/how-can-i-determine-the-running-mac-os-x-version-programmatically question. But your link seems to be only for 10.6

Comment: 10.6.7 was an example of version string; ‘e.g.’ means ‘for example’. There’s nothing in the answer that’s specific to an OS X version.

Comment: If the different implementations depend on what APIs are available you should probably check for features instead of OS versions. For example "if (![someInstance respondsToSelector:@selector(fooBar:withMoarArgs:)]) { [someInstance foo:a withMoarArgs:b] } else { custom implementation }". Edit: Which is also what Graham Lee said in the thread you linked to at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157759/how-can-i-determine-the-running-mac-os-x-version-programmatically/159927#159927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use gestalt in one of my Apps succesfuly. Some code snippet to check wether the user is running 10.7.0 or higher:

```
SInt32 OSXversionMajor, OSXversionMinor;
if(Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMajor, &OSXversionMajor) == noErr && Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMinor, &OSXversionMinor) == noErr)
{
    if(OSXversionMajor == 10 && OSXversionMinor >= 7)
    {
         // Foo
    }
}
```

Comment: That will break if Apple ever goes to 11.

Comment: @PeterHosey I still hope that Apple deprecates and removes AppKit with 11...