# Is it possible to submit to Mac App Store excluding OsX Mavericks to download

Tags: objective-c, macos, app-store, mac-app-store

I discovered a bug in my application that only occurs in OSx Mavericks (10.9) but works on all others (10.7 - 10.8).

It will take some time to fix it, but I still want to release for the others.

Do you know if it is possible to exclude Mavericks from the mac app store. I have seen people filtering based on mac model for performance reasons. What would be the best approach other than fixing the bug obviously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot exclude a later OS version in the Mac App Store.
If you have a workaround (disable feature or something) on Mavericks then you can check the OS version on runtime (see [OS X version checking in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115373/os-version-checking-in-cocoa)) and submit a new version to the Mac App Store and request a expedite review.

Answer (score 1):

Mavericks is 10.9, not 10.8. And - "no you can't exclude newer versions of OS X".

Answer (score 1):

[image]you can stick with the old base sdk but you cant exclude it as a deployment target

Comment: how do you "stick with the old base sdk" ?